# Determine $E(X^3)$ if $X$ is $\exp(2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, exponential-distribution

I want to calculate $E(X^3)$ knowing that $X\sim\exp(2).$ I have tried using the definition of expected value to calculate $E(X^3)$ and got the integral $$ \int_0^\infty x^3 2e^{-2x} \,dx.$$ Is this correct or is there an easier way to do it that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Looks right to me.

You can calculate that integral by doing integration by parts three times. Or if you already know $E(X^2),$ once is enough, because integration by parts gives you an expression in terms of $E(X^2).$

That’s how I would expect you to do the question (at least, if you don’t know the integral already.)

---

A more advanced trick lets you calculate all $E(X^n)$ at once, using the Moment Generating Function:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{E(X^n)}{n!}t^n&=E\left(e^{tX}\right)\\&=\int_0^\infty 2e^{tx}e^{-2x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{2}{t-2}e^{(t-2)x}\Bigg|_0^\infty\\
&=\frac{1}{1-t/2}\quad\text{Assuming }t<2
\end{align}$$

This shows that $$E(X^n)=\frac{n!}{2^n}$$

Comment: More a comment than an answer. Moreover there is a direct method by recognizing a $\Gamma$ integral.

Comment: @JeanMarie at this level of probability knowledge, I don’t know many people who know the $\Gamma$ function. But I added more to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it is not true everywhere. In my country, $\Gamma$ function is now introduced earlier than before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Gamma r.v. density function, i.e., if $X\sim Gamma(n, \lambda)$, then
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \frac{\lambda ^ n}{ \Gamma(n)}e^{-\lambda x} x^{n-1} dx = 1
$$
In your case
$$
\int x ^ 3 \cdot 2e ^{-2x} dx = 2\cdot \frac{3!}{2^4}\int\frac{2^4}{3!}x ^ 3 e ^{-2x}dx = \frac{3!}{2^3}
$$

where $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute $E[X^n]$ by taking derivative of mgf $n$ times and evaluate at $t=0$.

$M_X(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t} = \frac{2}{2 - t}$, then $\frac{d^nM_X}{d t^n} = \frac{2n!}{(2-t)^{n+1}}$ and at $t = 0$, we get $E[X^n] = \frac{n!}{2^n}$

Comment: If OP knows what mgf is, it is not necessary to do $n$-fold differentiation, since $$\frac2{2-t}=\frac{1}{1-t/2}$$ has an easily deduced power series.